# Не могу пройти авторизацию через бд Spring Security

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jwt, spring-data-jpa

осваиваю Spring boot + JWT + data jpa + postgre. не могу пройти авторизацию, выскакивает BadCredentialsException.. Пишет в логах даже по-русски "пользователь заблокирован", т.е. должен прийти ответ с токеном, а приходит 403. Все что надо из базы подгружается - проверил по дебагу.

Происходит это на метода authenticate в контроллере и дальше Exception

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException: Учетная запись пользователя заблокирована
```

вот некоторый код, ниже ссылка на репо:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    private static final String ADMIN_ENDPOINT = "/people/admin/**";
    private static final String LOGIN_ENDPOINT = "/people/login";
  
    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(LOGIN_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(ADMIN_ENDPOINT).hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }
}

@PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody AuthRequestDto authRequestDto) {
        try {
            String personName = authRequestDto.getPersonName();
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(personName, authRequestDto.getPassword()));
            Person person = personDAO.findByPersonName(personName);
            if (person == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
            }
            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(personName, person.getRoles());
            Map<Object, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("personName", personName);
            response.put("token", token);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid data");
        }
    }
```

ссылка на репозиторий -
https://github.com/papoff8295/SpringMVCApp1/tree/dataJPA

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, ты хочешь настроить в своем "ресурсном" сервере OAuth2 авторизацию?
Посмотри про это в офиц. доке по Спринг Секьюрити: [OAuth 2.0 Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver)

Там все достаточно просто:

1. Сначала [настраиваешь в application.yml где приложению искать публичный ключ для проверки подписи JWT токена](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-jwkseturi):

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://idp.example.com/.well-known/jwks.json
```

2. Потом [настраиваешь SecurityConfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-sansboot):

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .mvcMatchers("/messages/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_message:read")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    }
}
```

Comment: да..я все это сделал. но не принимает логин и пароль через пост запрос, сервер присылает 403, в дебаге exception LockedException. где-то есть ошибочка, которую я не вижу замыленным глазом